# JavaScript document.write br

Tags: javascript, document.write

How do you write in JavaScript `"<br>"`? I don't want it to break and go to the next line, I just want the html tag to be written. Something like: "the break tag in html is ..."

Example of what I want below.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    document.write('"<br>"');
</script>
```

Comment: Don't use `document.write`, see the warning in [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#document.write%28%29). Use DOM methods instead.

Comment: You do it the same way in `document.write()` as you would do it if you were putting it into th  HTML directly, by using entities.

Answer (score 2):

Just use [HTML entities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity).

> ```
> Character  Entity   Note
> ---------  -------  ----------------------------------------------------------------
>     &      &amp;    Character indicates the beginning of an entity. 
>     <      &lt;     Character indicates the beginning of a tag 
>     >      &gt;     Character indicates the ending of a tag 
>     "      &quote;  Character indicates the beginning and end of an attribute value.
> ```

```js
document.write('The break tag in html is &lt;br&gt;.');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use HTML entities of `<` and `>` :

```
< : &lt;
> : &gt;

&lt;br&gt; = <br>
```

Hoep this helps.

---

```js
document.write("I don't want &lt;br&gt; to break and go to the next line");
```